# node.js(Javascript) google-api-nodejs-client - list messages

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

My question was voted down, so i am rewriting it hopefully this is more succinct

I am stuck at writing a javascript function to list messages in inbox.

Using - official "google-api-nodejs-client", node.js, electron, (and javascript)
Goal: list messages in gmail inbox
For that to work i need to authorize first then ask for the messages

**Authorize**
 - [I copied the code from google node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) 
 - this works in electron (well actually node.js as it is a command line script).

**Ask for Messages**
 - [Google has an example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs), i copied it adjusted some parts but doesn't work. I think the example i am working from is not designed for the node.js "google-api-nodejs-client".
 - Maybe it needs a different authorize

This is the listmessages function from the google example, i can't seem to figure out how to make this work with the authorize from list labels. This is what i have tried

- changing gapi to google
- changing userId to 'me'
- changing givig it a query

Does not use a client library.

```js
Does not use a client library.

/**
 * Retrieve Messages in user's mailbox matching query.
 *
 * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @param  {String} query String used to filter the Messages listed.
 * @param  {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function listMessages(userId, query, callback) {
  var getPageOfMessages = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      result = result.concat(resp.messages);
      var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
      if (nextPageToken) {
        request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          'userId': userId,
          'pageToken': nextPageToken,
          'q': query
        });
        getPageOfMessages(request, result);
      } else {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  };
  var initialRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    'userId': userId,
    'q': query
  });
  getPageOfMessages(initialRequest, []);
}
```

This is the aurhorize function that works to list labels.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth) {
  var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var labels = response.labels;
    if (labels.length == 0) {
      console.log('No labels found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Labels:');
      for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var label = labels[i];
        console.log('- %s', label.name);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The flow of your program should look like this:

[image]

Then you can use the api to list messages. (just to get you started):

`export function listMessages(oauth2Client, userId, query, callback) {
    const gmail = google.gmail('v1');
    gmail.users.messages.list({
        auth: oauth2Client,
        userId: 'me',
    }, (err, response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}`

Notice the oauth2Client parameter. This is the object you get from your function authorize. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: did my answer help you @david?

Comment: It is confusing that how we use those methods is different from how Google documents them online.

Comment: I  gave a positive vote for the effort in the flowchart.